# Kendo UI styling breaks form control layout

Tags: kendo-ui, form-control

I am trying to build a form with a simple bootstrap row/column layout. Before I add the Kendo class styling the controls appear stacked as expected:

```
<div class="col-lg-3 form-group">
    <label for="CaseName" class="form-label">Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control-sm" />
</div>
```

[image: Form controls vertical]

Once I add the Kendo class for styling the layout becomes horizontal:

```
<div class="col-lg-3 form-group">
    <label for="CaseName" class="form-label">Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control k-textbox" />
</div>
```

[image: Form controls horizontal]

Anyone know how to override whatever is happening in the k-textbox class?

Thanks.

Comment: Add `width: 100%` style or use a css class that does the same.

Answer (score 0):

As per Kendu Guide on Bootstrap here: [Using form-control Bootstrap CSS Class](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/third-party/using-kendo-with-twitter-bootstrap#using), we have to use custom styling to ensure the `form-label` and `form-control` behaves as expected:

```
<style>
    .form-control.k-widget
    {
        padding: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }

    .form-control.k-widget:not(.k-autocomplete)
    {
        border-width: 0;
    }
</style>
```